# WCF Socket Connection Aborted: Communication Exception

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, timing

I'm having some difficulty setting up a WCF interface.  I can connect fine, but as soon as I start sending certain data, I get the following exception:

`The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an         underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '01:39:59.9084817'.`

From looking at a few other questions, I found that this could be due to inefficient timeout.  So I increased the following parameters to 100 minutes just for kicks.

```
tcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
tcpBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
tcpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
```

However, this exception is thrown the same instant a certain function is called so I don't think that is the problem.  The peculiar thing though is that the exception always shows a time almost the same as whatever I put into those parameters, regardless of how much time actually passed.

I found that I can send the standard types like object, string, int, etc but whenever I try to send a custom type, this error is thrown.  That is telling me it might be a bad reference somewhere.  Does this make sense?

UPDATE:
Had a chance to upload the code.

Here is the client side:

```
namespace GenericWCF
{
/// <summary>
/// TODO: Update summary.
/// </summary>
[ServiceContract()]
public interface SimWCFInterface
{
    [OperationContract()]
    void SimpleMessage(string message);

    [OperationContract()]
    List<CustomObj> GetDataPoints();
}
}
```

and the server side:

```
namespace DifferentNamespace
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// TODO: Update summary.
/// </summary>
[ServiceContract()]
public interface SimWCFInterface
{
    [OperationContract()]
    void SimpleMessage(string message);

    [OperationContract()]
    List<CustomObj> GetDataPoints();
}
```

and the actual implementation

```
namespace DifferentNamespace
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

/// <summary>
/// TODO: Update summary.
/// </summary>
[ServiceContract()]
public interface SimWCFInterface
{
    public void SimpleMessage(string message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("This is a simple message wcf");
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }

    public List<CustomObj> GetDataPoints()
    {
        List<CustomObj> points = new List<CustomObj>();

        return points;
    }
}
```

So there really isn't anything special going on I don't think.  `SimpleMessage` runs fine no problem.  If I change `GetDataPoints` to return a regular `object`, it works fine as well.  The problem only occurs when I return that `CustomObj`.  One thing I noticed just now is that client and server side live in different namespaces, so could that be an issue?  Also, I'm using a tcp conneciton.  I'll post that code in a moment.

EDIT:

The tcp connection code:

client

```
    private string endPointAddress;
    private NetTcpBinding tcpBinding;

    public void Connect(string ipAddress, string portNumber, string interfaceName)
    {
        try
        {
            interfaceName = interfaceName.Substring(interfaceName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);

            endPointAddress = "net.tcp://" + ipAddress + ":" + portNumber + "/" + interfaceName;

            tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
            tcpBinding.TransactionFlow = false;
            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
            tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
            tcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
            tcpBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
            tcpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
            tcpBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = false;
            tcpBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            tcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10000000;
            tcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 10000000;
            tcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 10000000;

            EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(endPointAddress);
            _SimChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<SimWCFInterface>(tcpBinding, endpointAddress);
            _SimWCFInterface = _SimChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

            //test connection...working
            _SimWCFInterface.SimpleMessage("what a message");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

and the server

```
static public void CreateSimHost(string IPAdd, string port, Type interfaceType, Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            string interfaceName = interfaceType.ToString();

            interfaceName = interfaceName.Substring(interfaceName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);

            // Create the url that is needed to specify where the service should be started
            urlService = "net.tcp://" + IPAdd + ":" + port + "/" + interfaceName;

            host = new ServiceHost(serviceType);

            // The binding is where we can choose what transport layer we want to use. HTTP, TCP ect.
            tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding
            {
                TransactionFlow = false
            };

            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
            tcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
            tcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None; // <- Very crucial
            tcpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            tcpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            tcpBinding.ReliableSession.Ordered = false;
            tcpBinding.ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;

            // Add a endpoint
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(interfaceType, tcpBinding, urlService);
            host.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that the error says "This **could be**.....a receive timeout being exceeded...".   In this case, it does not sound like a timeout issue.  Rather, it sounds like a serialization issue with your custom object - or perhaps your service doesn't reference the assembly that contains the custom object.   If you can provide more details and some code example (especially of the object in question) we can provide further help.

Comment: Try to increase to 200 instead of 100. 100 mins = 1:39 mins. So it does not effect you at all if the time out is the real issue.

Comment: @HwasooLee I highly doubt that will change anything.  I initially had it set to 2 minutes and the exception came up at 1:59 and then I changed it to 5 minutes and it came up at 4.59... and all of these occurred seconds after the startup of the program.

Comment: @Tim do both the client and the server have to reference the same dll?  Right now I have two separate copies of the dll used by the service in each project's respective bin folder.

Comment: @Josh - Yes, they will both have to reference the same DLL.  They'll need their own copy, but it needs to be the same one.